# LSI Megaraid beeping after disk replacement

Tags: vmware-esxi, megaraid, megacli

On my ESXi server, I had to replace a physical disk of my RAID.

Now that disk is replaced and rebuild finished, alarm continue beeping, and I don't understand by why, because everything seems to be optimal:

```
/opt/lsi/MegaCLI # ./MegaCli -LDInfo -Lall -aALL


Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-6, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
Size                : 2.725 TB
Sector Size         : 512
Is VD emulated      : No
Parity Size         : 930.5 GB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 256 KB
Number Of Drives    : 8
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Enabled
Encryption Type     : None
PI type: No PI

Is VD Cached: No


Virtual Drive: 1 (Target Id: 1)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-6, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
Size                : 3.637 TB
Sector Size         : 512
Is VD emulated      : Yes
Parity Size         : 3.637 TB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 256 KB
Number Of Drives    : 4
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Enabled
Encryption Type     : None
PI type: No PI

Is VD Cached: No
```

Running a `./MegaCli -PDList -aALL` indicate no Media Error Count, but physical drives of my Virtual Drive: 1 indicates "Other Error Count: 6" and I don't know how to have more information about these errors.

I know that I can silence this alarm, but if I doo, alarm will restart on the next reboot.

Is there a way to now why precisely the alarm is On? Is there a way to disable it even after reboot (but of course, not disable entirely this alarm which must turn on after a new disk crash).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the "Copy Back" feature is turned on. Basically a drive that was replaced has to be in the same slot because if not, it will keep beeping. Rather annoying functionality imho so I disable "Copy Back" on my servers like this:
https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161502838/megaraid-controller-still-beeps-after-rebuild-completes-and-vd-i

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but state of my RAID is optimal, and server still beeping after a reboot, enven if copy back is disabled:
`/opt/lsi/storcli/storcli /c0 show copyback` gives Copy Back OFF / SSDSMARTerEnabled OFF / SMARTerEnabled    OFF